# Does read/unread information exist in Thunderbird's .msf file?

Tags: thunderbird

I ran [gmail backup](http://www.gmail-backup.com/), which marked all my gmail messages as read.  Ugh.  I actually use that read/unread information.  I had just installed Thunderbird, and it shows hundreds of messages in "All Mail" that are unread.  Only it had only downloaded the headers, not the messages.  So something in Thunderbird knows they are unread, but I'm not sure exactly what.

I [read](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=204688) that there are two files for any mail folder, an mbox-format file and a .msf file.  The mbox format file for "All Mail" does not have all the messages.  However, the .msf file is pretty big, and I wonder if it has all the read/unread info.

If it does, I would consider extracting it, and going back and reapplying it programmatically (say, using [gmail4j](http://code.google.com/p/gmail4j/)).

Answer (score 1):

The `msf` file is using Mork format so reading it is pretty complicated. Fortunately, you don't have to: the mails in the mbox file have a special `X-Mozilla-Status` header. It's a hexadecimal value combining [a number of flags](http://www.eyrich-net.org/mozilla/X-Mozilla-Status.html?en). The lowest bit in this header (`0x0001`) is only set for messages that are read - if it isn't there then the message is unread.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, as I said in my question, I think I don't have all the mail downloaded ("All Mail" has 87 X-Mozilla-Status lines, my mailbox has thousands of emails), just the headers.

Comment: Well, then [Mork format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%28file_format%29) it is. Please accept my condolences.

Comment: Yep, I've read docs on it.  I also tried http://www.jwz.org/hacks/mork.pl, which complained bitterly.  However, I still don't know if read/unread information is in that .msf file, i.e. if it's worth pursuing.

Comment: @dfrankow: It is there, just not easily accessible. Note that there are apparently two variants of the Mork format and jwz's script might be targeting the wrong one.

Comment: Apparently so does Perl's Mozilla::Mork (http://search.cpan.org/~kript/Mozilla-Mork-0.01/lib/Mozilla/Mork.pm). :(  I tried it on "All Mail.msf", and it produces all kinds of "unparsable cell" warnings.

Comment: Also the Gmail data export mbox file has a similar header: `X-Gmail-Labels:Unread` that preserves the information whether an email was unread.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to read only Header and the Summary part of your Emails, then you can read it from your .msf file of your Mozilla Thunderbird, Since The .msf file is just a index file of Mozilla Thunderbird. So you cannot read all the information of your Emails from it. To read your Emails, you first need to find the location of your **INBOX** File which doesn't have an extension. 
you can find its location from here in your Thunderbird Email client:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\wb09b73f.default\ImapMail\imap.googlemail.com
```

Then, copy it and paste it to other location of your system and rename it to **INBOX.mbox** and then you can easily import it from your Mozilla Thunderbird and can Easily read your Emails after importing it on your Thunderbird.